# Spring Boot 2.0.0 & static resources with different domains for the same app

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I have migrated a web app from Spring Boot 1.5.10 to 2.0.0, which serves content trough different domains and it is deployed with Heroku. The main domain works fine, but with the other ones the static elements like Javascript, CSS, images and icons don't work and the browser arises this error:

**Refused to execute script from '' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled**

The static resources are located at:

`/resources/static/css`

`/resources/static/js`

`/resources/static/images`

All domains are secured with a Let's Encrypt SSL certificate, provided by Heroku. The domains are all redirected, including the main one, with a CNAME to the address provided by Heroku.

The main domain has access to all the content, and the secondary ones just can access to the content inside a directory. For example:

`maindomain.com/1/` works fine but `secondarydomain.com/1/` doesn't work.

What makes a secondary domain different from the main one, is that with an implementation of `HandlerInterceptor` we control that they just can access to the content from its directory. This is the code from the preHandle implementation:

```
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

    serverName = request.getServerName();

    if("POST".equals(request.getMethod())){
        return true;
    }

    //We check if the request comes from one of the main domains
    if(!checkRentalWebsURL(RwConstants.SERVER_NAMES, serverName)){

        if(idweb == null){
            Web web = webRepository.getWebByDomain(serverName);  
            if(web != null){
                idweb = web.getIdweb();
            } else {
                response.sendRedirect(RwConstants.RW_URL);
            }
        }

        String URI = request.getRequestURI();
        String rootURI = "/" + idweb + "/";

        if(URI.equals("/") || !URI.startsWith(rootURI)){ 
            URI = rootURI;

            RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(request.getContextPath() + URI);
            requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);

        }
    } 

    return true;
}
```

I've tried to solve it setting this code at an extension of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`:

```
http
 .authorizeRequests()
    .requestMatchers(PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations()).permitAll()
```

Comment: did you find the solution?

Comment: @vashishth Iguan2 at [GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8172#issuecomment-390321160) has given me this solution, which I haven't tested yet:
I found that after migrating to 2.0.1, all static resource requests go to my interceptor. After excluding the static resource path in the intercepter registration, it works for me. Not sure if this can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to exclude the paths of the different static resources, in the interceptor registration, at the implementation of `WebMvcConfigurer`. This is an extract of the code:

```
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    ...        
    registry.addInterceptor(rootDomainInterceptor())
            .excludePathPatterns("/js/**", "/css/**", "/images/**", "/webjars/**");

}
```

`rootDomainInterceptor()` is an implementation of `HandleInterceptor`, which I use to deal with the different domains accessing the app.

Answer (score 0):

I recently struggled with a similar issue as well. I just added the whole resources directory.

```
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        ...        
        registry.addInterceptor(rootDomainInterceptor())
                .excludePathPatterns("/recources/**");
    
    }
```

Comment: The author of the post has already answered 3 years ago, so reposting the same answer is not a fair affair, especially 3 years later. Did you read answers first ?