# Load a index.html dependent of domain in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot project as backend and an Angular project for the frontend.

For now, I use spring to service angular from the static resources, but coming soon I will need to load different angular projects depending on the domain used to access to service.

I can load different static resources by default depending on the domain in Spring Boot?

Example:

```java
resources.add("domain1.com", "resources/static/domain1/");
resources.add("domain2.com", "resources/static/domain2/");
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot 2.0.0 & static resources with different domains for the same app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49742053/spring-boot-2-0-0-static-resources-with-different-domains-for-the-same-app)

Comment: @pringi yes I think it will resolve that problem.

Comment: Jums... maybe... I will try. Thanks.